# Why does a one-line mysql query/fetch array statement not work?

Tags: php, mysql

I have run into this problem multiple times, and I cannot figure out why it happens. When I build a MySQL statement like the following it works just fine:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$something'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $someVar=$row['whatever'];
    //and so on
    }
```

But when I combine the first two statements to the following:

```
while($row=mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$something'")))
```

and try to loop through them, the page seems to loop infinitely without loading or returning an error. Why doesn't the second statement work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) executes the query and returns a record id which [`mysql_fetch_array`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) uses to fetch the next row. When you chain them together like you've tried doing, each iteration of the `while` loop will exectute the query, return a new record id and fetch the first row. As long as there's at least one row, it'll end up doing this in an infinite loop.